# Initialize Abstract Property in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, abstract-class, spring-framework-beans

I am wondering how to initialize a variable in abstract class in Spring Framework. I cannot change the constructor which is already present. I have referred to http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/47496-dependency-inject-abstract-class-property but the property has `null` value.

I have used `abtract=true` in my xml file.

My Abstract Class:

```
    package com.hi;
    public abstract class Xyz implements Serializable{
            private String path;
            public String getPath(){return path;}
            public void setPath(String path){this.path = path;}
            private void init(){
                //path will be used to get the file from the location
            }
            public Serializable getExpr(){
                 init();
            }
    }
```

My Inherited Class:

```
public class Abc extends Xyz implements Serializable{
   private Abc(String a){
       super(a,TYPE.data);
   }
   public static Abc of(){
      return new Abc(a);
   }
}
```

My xml file:

```
<bean id="xyz"
          class="com.hi.Xyz"
          abstract="true">
        <property name="path" value="${PATH}" />
</bean>
```

The inherited class does not have to get the file. So the abstract class can have the path directly injected and use the path.

Comment: Provide full code, please.

Comment: @egorlitvinenko Added few more details

Comment: How you are trying to read the value from Xyz class? Since it is abstract then you have to extend this class to another class and read its property thru this concrete class which extedns Xyz.

Comment: I have used another class that extends this abstract class `Xyz`. But the abstract class has `init()` in which the `path` is being used to create an inputstream.

Comment: Give us code of init, please, and where it is called. Maybe you should pass it as constructor argument.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share the `init` code. The method simply takes the path and creates an inputstream. The path informationis present in a config file, which is then pulled by the spring xml file and injected into the abstract class.

Comment: @egorlitvinenko - I cannot pass it as constructor argument. I will have to make changes in the classes which extend this abstract class. I am looking for direct injection into Xyz abstract class.

Comment: If in abstract class path instantion hardcoded to config, why do you not override init method in inherited class?

Comment: The `init` method is not getting overrided in the inherited class. the `init` is called from an other method of the abstract class which is being called in the inherited class

Comment: @egorlitvinenko Provided some more info